# formatting dictionary for Alamofire

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3, alamofire

**This question is more about Swift & and Dictionaries than Alamofire itself**

I need to create a record via a webservice, and I'm using Alamofire. For some reason I have too many quotes than desired and the webservice refuses my call

If I simulate the call via curl the webservice receives :

```
{"records"=>[{"id"=>"2", "node"=>{"children"=>[{"specifications"=>"Specs", "description"=>"Fee", "line_item"=>{"sale_price"=>123.4, 
"amount"=>1, "vat_percentage"=>21, "unit_price"=>99.5}}]}}], "action"=>"create", "collection"=>"invoices", "controller"=>"api/v2/api"}
```

If I do the call via Alamofire in my app, the webservice receives:

```
{"records"=>[{"id"=>"2", "node"=>{"children"=>[{"specifications"=>"Specs", "description"=>"Fee", "line_item"=>{"sale_price"=>"123.4", 
"amount"=>"1", "vat_percentage"=>"21", "unit_price"=>"99.5"}}]}}], "action"=>"create", "collection"=>"invoices", "controller"=>"api/v2/api"}
```

As you can see each number has quotes wrapped around itself (eg. "99.5" vs 99.5, causing the webservice to flip.

I tweaked around but can't find on how to fix this in Swift. The way I created my payload for Alamofire is:

```
let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "id": id as AnyObject,
            "node" : [
                "children": [[
                    "description" : lineDescription,
                    "specifications" : lineSpecifications,
                    "line_item" : [
                        "amount" : 1,
                        "unit_price" : feePrice,
                        "sale_price" : feePrice,
                        "vat_percentage" : 21

                    ]
                ]] as AnyObject
            ] as AnyObject
        ]
let parameters = ["records" : [jsonObject as AnyObject]]    

Alamofire.request(urlPath, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: ["X-API-KEY": apiKey, "Content-type application":"json", "Accept application" : "json"]).responseString() {

            response in switch (response.result) {

blah blah
}
```

where the variables lineDescription and lineSpecifications are Strings and feePrice is a Double

Comment: Please send the error message you are getting while trying to perform the web service.

Comment: The error message is : Method not allowed for this collection. This isn't really helpfull. So I did a tail on the production log of the webservice (ssh test@site tail -f shared/log/production.log) where I can see that with Curl it's sent without quotes around int/doubles and from Swift/Alamofire with quotes

Comment: Sorry, you need to convert those into NSNumber and then try sending it.

Comment: I tried "line_item" : [
                        "amount" : 1 as NSNumber,
                        "unit_price" : feePrice as NSNumber,
                        "sale_price" : feePrice as NSNumber,
                        "vat_percentage" : 21 as NSNumber
                    
                    ]
But that doesn't change te result (still has quotes)

Comment: Found the solution! Needed to add :  encoding: JSONEncoding.default to the Alamofire request

Comment: Awesome.....!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment I needed to add an encoding to the request. To close the question and to show a more friendly formatted solution this answer :

```
Alamofire.request(urlPath, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: ["X-API-KEY": apiKey, "Content-type application":"json", "Accept application" : "json"]).responseString() {
```

should be :

```
Alamofire.request(urlPath, method: .post, parameters: parameters,  encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["X-API-KEY": apiKey, "Content-type application":"json", "Accept application" : "json"]).responseString() {
```

Comment: This encoding also allows you to correctly parse `request.raw_post` on a ruby on rails server. Saved my life here!